Can't use latest open JDK 21 with spot bugs 4.7.3.0 in Eclipse
I am trying to build my workspace with open JDK 21.
I am getting errors like the one below from the spot bugs plugin.
The same is working fine in JDK 11.
Could you please help me to resolve this issue?
Error Message:  09:32:30
[INFO] --- spotbugs-maven-plugin:4.7.3.0:spotbugs (spotbugs) @ BrowserSystem --- 09:32:32 
[INFO] Fork Value is true 
[java] The following errors occurred during analysis: 
[java] Error scanning java/lang/Object for referenced classes 
[java] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65 
[java] At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199) 
[java] At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180) 
[java] At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.<init>(FBClassReader.java:35) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:48)
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261)
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:75)
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:261) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.buildReferencedClassSet(FindBugs2.java:806) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:249) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.runMain(FindBugs.java:395) 
[java] At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.main(FindBugs2.java:1231) 
[java] Error scanning java/lang/Enum for referenced classes 
[java] ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 65

I need to build my workspace with open JDK21. For that what are things I have to modify to make it work?

You most likely just need to update the POM file to use a newer version of the maven spotbugs plugin.  The latest is 4.8.6.4.
